# Recibir datos en controlador MVC 5

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo el siguiente problema estoy tratando de enviar unos datos desde ajax a mi controlador mvc pero no logró recuperarlos este es mi codigo:

```
   var Url = '@Url.Action("Save", "InspectionDailies")';
    var user = 0;
    function getval(sel) {
        user = sel.value;
    }

    $("#save").on("click", function () {

        var idinsp = $('#bookId').val();
        if (user == 0) {
            swal('¡Alert!', 'Select a User!.', 'error');
            return;
        }
        var ids = { "data": [{ "list": list, "user": user }] }
        $.post(Url, ids, function (data) {
            swal('Info', 'Success', 'success');
            $("#modalUser").trigger('click');
            location.reload();
        });
    });
```

y el controlador es este:

```
public class InspectionDailiesController : Controller
{
 [HttpPost, ActionName("Save")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Saved(string ids)
    {
        dynamic jsonObject = ids;
        var id = string.Empty;
        var user = string.Empty;

        var inspectionDaily = await db.InspectionDaily.FindAsync(id);
        if (inspectionDaily == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        try
        {
            inspectionDaily.IDUser = int.Parse(id);
            inspectionDaily.Status = 2;
            inspectionDaily.IdInspectionStates = 2;
            db.Entry(inspectionDaily).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            TempData["msg"] = "<script>alert('Change succesfully');</script>";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        ViewBag.Userdb = new SelectList(CombosHelper.GetUsersDB(), "IDUser", 
 "FirstName");
        ViewBag.IdInspectionStates = new SelectList(db.InspectionStates, 
"IdInspectionStates", "Description", inspectionDaily.IdInspectionStates);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
}
```

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: el controlador espera un string y le estas enviando un objeto que tiene un array. que deseas hacer?

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta estoy enviando un array de ids y el id de un usuario pero no se como recibirlo en el controlador.

Comment: Probaste de usar un ViewModel para recibirlo? Yo generalmente lo trabajo de esa manera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias formas de hacer esto. Te dejo acá una:

En tu JS haces algo como esto:

```
  var cadenaIds = list.join();
  var form = new FormData();
  form.append("listaIds", cadenaIds);
  form.append("user", user);
  $.post(....);
```

En tu CS:

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> Saved(string listaIds, string user){
       string[] arregloIds = listaIds.Split(new char[] {','})
       //si los id son Int puede iterar sobre el arreglo y haces el parse Int por cada String

      //......
  }
```

Otra opcion pudiera ser que en tu JS uses Json.Stringify y en tu CS deserializas ese Json.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Lo probare y te cuento gracias

Comment: Funciono perfecto gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Excelente!!!!. A lo orden para eso estamos